# How to mask out bits for a pseudorandom number generator

Tags: python, random

I am constructing a pseudorandom number generator for hashing purposes.  We are required to use a certain algorithm. The algorithm is as follows:

- Initialize an integer R to be equal to 1 every time the tabling routine is called
- On each successive call for a random number, set R = R*5
- Mask all but the lower order n+2 bits of the product and place the result in R 
  (2^n is the size of the table)
- Set P = R/4 and return

My issue lies within the third step of the algorithm. What does it mean to mask out the lower order n+2 bits? I have read a lot online so I have some what of an idea, but further clarification would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It means you take the number modulo 2^(2+n). This is so that 0 <= R < 2^(2+n), which means that 0 <= P < 2^n. One way to do this:

```
R %= 2 ** (2+n)
```

Using bit-shift operations, which could be more efficient (note that mask is a constant, so you only need to compute it once):

```
mask = (1 << 2+n) - 1
R &= mask
```

The reason it's called "masking out all but the lower-order bits" is if you write R in binary, it's the same as removing everything except the last 2+n binary digits.